# How to calculate two partical derivative?

Tags: calculus

I read a book but I don't know how to infer the formula in the bellow picture. marked as red retangle, Can someone give me detail process, thanks.

[image]

Comment: seems like the change of variables formula

Comment: @Ilya The question is talking about Cartesian coordinates that use polar coordinates variables  to show it.

Comment: That's just the chain rule from what I can see.

Comment: They are applying the chain rule to $\partial u/\partial x$ exactly as they did to $u$ in the first step.